Young adult novel, read in early '60s, about a spacecraft travelling from Earth to a mysterious purple planet
UK? YA novel. Travel from Earth in spacecraft which is actually constructed as an amphibious 'Flying Boat' - takes off from ocean and gradually gains altitude to space. Destination is a mysterious planet (possibly named 'Imperator') with purple appearance, sometimes wreathed with "purple streamers". Plant life proves to be adapted to be fireproof. Planet proves to be periodically engulfed with combustion.
The plant snapping shut is indeed how it responds to a small flame.
I don't recall any "flying saucer"
style craft.
I believe you have indeed identified the book.

Did the main character get his hand trapped in a plant when he lights a match and the plant snaps shut?

Was the spacecraft shaped like a sphere embedded in a disk (like the planet Saturn with a wide ring? Did the main character encounter an official government expedition who used a conventional rocket ship? Did something incapacitate the mad scientist so main character has to follow the rocket back to Earth using flying boat?

This is Emperor of Space by Tom Allum. It was first published in 1959, and again in 1960 as Boy Beyond the Moon. I've not been able to find a copy, and while there seems to be conflicting sources as to whether the planet is called "Imperator" or if it's called "Emperor", the cover inner-sleeve calls the planet "Emperor".
Here is the full synopsis of the book as described in the cover inner-sleeve, courtesy of this ebay listing:

Guy Abbott first sees the mysterious planet Emperor in the glory of its purple streamers through Professor Harvey's telescope. When Guy meets the well-known professor and is invited to his home, he can not guess that exciting consequences lie ahead.
President of his high school astronautical society, Guy is delighted to learn that the professor is a famous expert in the field of interplanetary travel-a theoretical science, although many rockets have landed on the moon. The professor's greatest dream is to visit Emperor, which he has studied for years. One thing in particular puzzles him: What causes the unusual purple streamers which surround the planet?
Professor Harvey has designed and built a circular spaceship, quite different from any of the rocket ships which travel into space. But the government agency in charge of space travel has turned down his invention and plans to use an "approved" rocket to reach Emperor. Determined to fulfill his lifelong dream, the professor searches in vain for volunteers to travel with him to the unknown planet.
Through a startling turn of events, the professor finds a crew, and Guy finds him- self hurtling through space with a strange group of shanghaied men as companions. The exciting details of the young boy's journey to Emperor, his adventures on the planet and his discovery of the mystery behind Emperor's purple streamers make a breath-taking story, full of action and suspense.
An unusual science fiction story, BOY BEYOND THE MOON is woven around accurate scientific information; the author's central characters are unusually well defined. Tom Allum writes, "It seems that many space authors for young people are so busy dazzling readers with science that the human story is neglected." Mr. Allum's story is an answer to this fault.
By combining science, adventure and human-interest elements, the author's story will interest every reader whose imagination is stirred by space travel, science fiction or adventure

The isfdb link above references a review in Galaxy Magazine, April 1961, this can be read thanks to the Internet Archive. This review calls the planet "Emperor", and also says it's good for young readers:

ALTHOUGH ALLUM’S story is built heavily on fortuitous coincidences, he manages enough suspense and adventure to captivate at least his juvenile audience.
A covey of escaped prisoners and a teenage youth are the unwilling crew shanghaied by the frustrated inventor of a gravity-controlling spaceship that has been rejected as impractical by the government. Following the death of the inventor-pilot on the planet Emperor, the success of the return trip depends entirely on the youngster’s untried skill at astronavigation under compulsion by the convicts.
Rating: (for youngsters) *** 1/2

From this post on the AbeBooks Community Forum, both the asker and answerer mention the planet having a "purple dust-tail" or "purple flames". The asker remembers the planet being called "Imperator", whereas the answerer says it's "Emperor":

aokkittycat666: "Imperator", planet with purple flames - A scientist is sent off in a spaceship to look at a planet passing through the solar system - this planet appears to have a purple dust-tail, so was named "Imperator". He discovers that the "dust" is actually a coating of purple flames coming off the planet.
Kuivinen - Might be BOY BEYOND THE MOON by Tom Allum, but the planet with purple flames in it is called "Emperor".

I found the following "mini-review" in a PDF document detailing a few example of books for young readers. The review indicates the book is good for ages seven and up, and it mentions they are travelling to the tenth planet of the solar system, which is called "Imperator":

Boy Beyond the Moon by Tom Allum. Alternate title "Emperor of Space". 1960? From Great Britain. A very well done science fiction novel suitable for boys age seven and older, at a guess. A modern-day English boy named Guy befriends a famous, reclusive scientist who has moved in across the moors. In time, he discovers that the scientist has built a working space ship. It isn't long before Guy finds himself trapped on that spaceship along with a gang of escaped prisoners and the now-insane professor, on a trip to the tenth planet of the solar system: Imperator. Adventure and excitement in abundance. Unfortunately, this book is also incredibly rare, at least in the USA.

From Kirkus Reviews there's a mention of "contamination by volcanic gasses", which is possibly the periodic combustion you recall. This review calls the planet "Emperor" as well:

There's a trip through space before they reach Emperor, which in certain seasons is subject to contamination by volcanic gases, but at other times offers the earth great resources, and it is the exploration of these facts that occupy most of the story. Relationships between the boy and the older men add a dimension to what would otherwise be a fairly routine projection of man into outer space.



The title may also be a matter of where it was published.  WorldCat lists 36 libraries with "Boy beyond the moon", 35 in the US and 1 in the Philippines; and 8 libraries with "Emperor of Space", in Ireland, the UK, and Australia.

I was probably ~12 and read this in (boys' Grammar) school. I don't recognise the covers from ISFDB, nor the illustrations in the EBAY listing. But this is the book. We were all learning Latin - that may be why I have 'Imperator'.
